# Osmdroid - Unable to load a map on-line

Tags: android, osmdroid

I’m using the osmdroid library to use openstreetmaps in my android application, but I’m unable to load the maps on-line, using wifi.
If I make de manual download of the maps (mbtiles file) and place it in the osmdroid filder in the device  it works fine and they are loaded by my application, but if I want that my application loads the maps from the web in real time it doesn´t work and the maps are not loaded.

In Logcat I get the following warning:

```
"Problem downloading Maptile: /4/8/8 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbiden"
```

I have the following permissions in Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

This is the code I use to load the maps with the osmdoid:

```
myOpenMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myMapController = myOpenMapView.getController();
myMapController.setZoom(4);
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: add this     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />   
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

Answer (score 1):

The issue mentionned by LordRaydenMK has been fixed in osmdroid 4.1.

So if this is the issue you have, you just have to update your osmdroid lib to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

> The default Apache HttpClient user-agent was recently banned from accessing tile.openstreetmap.org (server returns 403). As a result,
>   the Mapnik provider is no longer serving any tiles for osmdroid.
>
> OpenStreetMap's tile usage policy (
>   http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy ) says that a
>   "Valid User-Agent identifying application" must be sent. The current
>   user-agent osmdroid sends when it downloads a tile is
>   "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" which is pretty generic.
>
> I've created a patch that will send a user-agent that is more
>   compliant with OSM's tile usage policy. The new user-agent is
>   "osmdroid ([package name])" where [package name] is the package name
>   of the application using osmdroid.
>
> The patch can be found here: http://pastebin.com/kxBh1gQ5
>
> The patch is not very pretty, but it does its job.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=515